# mysql calculation on cross tables

Tags: mysql

I've three tables in mysql with data as below, and I would like to know how do I get the following output.  I don't know what's wrong with my coding?

```
select 
    rev.memberid,
    (sum(rev.earned)/rule.revperpoint) - sum(redeem.redeempoint) as bal
from rev
left join rule on rev.rulename = rule.rulename
inner join redeem on rev.memberid = redeem.memberid
group by rev.memberid;
```

table1 rule

```
rulename revperpoint
CNY       2
NY        1
```

table2        rev

```
memberid   earned  rulename
37638899   500.50  CNY
37638899   400.50  CNY
25264833   300.50  CNY
2526833    600.50  CNY
```

table3     redeem

```
memberid   redeempoint
25264833   100.00
25264833    50.00
```

expected output

```
memberid  bal
25264833  300.50
37638899  450.50
```

Comment: A general comment: INNER JOIN **after** OUTER JOIN negates its effects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on your desired result, the 4th line in table `rev` should be

```
25264833   600.50  CNY
```

And here you should not use `inner join`, cause it will only retrive record which memberid is `25264833`, try this:

```
select 
    rev.memberid,
    (sum(rev.earned) / rule.revperpoint ) - coalesce(redeem.redeempoint, 0) as bal
from rev
left join rule on rev.rulename = rule.rulename
left join (select memberid, sum(redeem.redeempoint) as redeempoint from redeem group by memberid) redeem on rev.memberid = redeem.memberid
group by rev.memberid;
```

And [**demo**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/0b57e/15) here.